# Аналоги BYTE, WORD, DWORD в Linux

Tags: c, c++, linux

В Windows есть определения типов BYTE, WORD, DWORD, которые объявляются в файле-заголовке WinDef.h и используются при программировании на C/C++. Какие типы являются аналогами для Linux и где они объявляются?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Аналоги типов `BYTE`, `WORD`, `DWORD` - это типы `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint32_t`, определенные в `stdint.h`.